# trying to make this code less messy in android, can anyone help?

Tags: android

i know that there must be a simpler way of doing this, i just don't understand how java works well enough, and i am struggling.  could someone perhaps point me in the right direction?

```
ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card1);
    ImageButton image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card2);
    ImageButton image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card3);
    ImageButton image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card4);
    ImageButton image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card5);
    ImageButton image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card6);
    ImageButton image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card7);
    ImageButton image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card8);
    ImageButton image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card9);
    ImageButton image10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card10);
    ImageButton image11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card11);
    ImageButton image12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card12);
    ImageButton image13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card13);
    ImageButton image14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card14);
    ImageButton image15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.card15);
    //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap2, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap3, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled4 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap4, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled5 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap5, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled6 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap6, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled7 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap7, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled8 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap8, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled9 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap9, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled10 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap10, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap11 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled11 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap11, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap12 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled12 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap12, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap13 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled13 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap13, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap14 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled14 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap14, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);
    Bitmap bMap15 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
    Bitmap bMapScaled15 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap15, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);

    image.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
    image2.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled2);
    image3.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled3);
    image4.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled4);
    image5.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled5);
    image6.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled6);
    image7.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled7);
    image8.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled8);
    image9.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled9);
    image10.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled10);
    image11.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled11);
    image12.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled12);
    image13.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled13);
    image14.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled14);
    image15.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled15);
```

Comment: how about using arrays? It looks like you're loading the same image multiple times, is it not possible to just set that same image over and over again instead of loading it so many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use an array to make the code less messy. Try something like this:

```
// UPDATE: change from String to int
int[] imageIds = new int[15] {
  R.id.card1, R.id.card2, R.id.card3,
  R.id.card4, R.id.card5, R.id.card6,
  R.id.card7, R.id.card8, R.id.card9,
  R.id.card10, R.id.card11, R.id.card12,
  R.id.card13, R.id.card14, R.id.card15
};

// load the source image only once
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vraag);
Bitmap bScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, buttonSize, buttonSize, true);

// render them all
ImageButton[] imageButtons = new ImageButton[15];
for(int i = 0; i < imageButtons.size(); i++) {
  ImageButton button = imageButtons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(imageIds[i]);
  button.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: findViewById(imageIds[i])   - takes an integer .. how can u pass a string

Comment: ohh.. I'm just helping with the refactor part, I don't actually know what any of these functions do, this was just my guess.

Comment: we must use reflection for this

Comment: thank you! this worked great, only needed to change to int like mentioned and for some reason had to do imageButtons.length() instead of size().  sorry if it seemed like an overly simple dumb question, but i'm new and trying to learn by doing.  it finally "clicked" for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

private ImageButton image[][]=new image[4][4];

```
Class c=Class.forName("com.test.R$id");
Integer i = new Integer(c.getField("ToolsbuttonR1C1").getInt(new R.id()));
```

// in this case let us suppose it is in R1C1 format - row and column

```
       for(int a=0,p=i;a<4;a++)
          {
                for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
                {
                    image[a][b]=(Button)findViewById(p); 
                    image[a][b].setOnClickListener(this); // an example
                    p++;
                }
        }
```

This might probably give u an error if the ids are not continuous.. like . if u have inserted 
rowwise in a tablerow layout in the xml ... the R.id will not be continuous.. so then u have to add another p++ in the first for loop...

this is how u can reduce the code..

Comment: thank you! this makes sense, and helps me understand the syntax better.